# How to Embed HTML/JS Frontend Files into a C++ Web Server Executable?

Tags: c++, webserver, httplib

I have a C++ application that uses httplib to serve an HTML/JS frontend from a folder. Currently, I require both the compiled C++ program and this folder for the application to work. Is there a way to embed the frontend folder into the C++ executable to create a single-file application?

Here's a minimal example of my current setup:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <httplib.h>

httplib::Server rest;

void run_rest_server(const int port)
{
    try
    {
        rest.set_mount_point("/", "./frontend");
        rest.listen("0.0.0.0", port);
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not start REST Server" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread(run_rest_server, 81).detach();
    while (true) { /*...*/ }
}
```

I found a resource-based approach, but it requires embedding each file individually, which is impractical for a frontend folder with hundreds of files. Is there a more efficient method?

Additionally, I'm continuously updating the frontend, so it's crucial for me to maintain an efficient development workflow. Ideally, I'd like a solution where I can still work on the frontend code separately and only need to run the C++ compiler to publish a new version of the application.

Comment: I may be a bit confused by your question. Particularly:
You want to embed the frontend folder into the C++ executable to create a single-file application. You also want to make changes to the frontend code (which would now be embedded into the application without needing to recompile.
These two goals seem to be incompatible. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I really tried to explain precisely what I want to accomplish, so I am wondering about the dislike. 

I was hoping that there is some kind of compiler flag, which includes my dedicated frontend folder at compile time. Therefore I could use a typicall frontend dev tool, to work on the code and after compilation of the c++ executable the folder is baked in the binary, in order to have a single file solution. So two instances (frontend folder and cpp) while coding, one instance (exe) after compiling in Visual Studio. Of course I am also happy about any different solution!

Comment: I'd probably combine a series of tools and scripts in order to achieve what I think you want, but its not an easy task: 1. Using python, for example, I'd use ziplib to archive the whole folder into a tmp zip file, read the bytes of that file, and write that to a const char data[] pointer in the c++ code. 2. Inside the c++ code, I'd use some zip librabry to write that binary data inside a tmp file, and attempt to extract it. But this technique only embeds the file before compilation time. I don't know if you mean to embed data after the script is compiled. If that's the case, idk how to do it.

Comment: But, imho, I don't see the point of achieving that for any application that is not an offline installer. Know that embeding files on the source code will increase its size in bytes, as you're literally writting data inside it. So, instead of moving / distributing a bunch of folders at once to your clients along with your exe, they're now stuck with a single but very big application. It ensures they cannot delete important data, but that's really it. Also, you're stuck with static files that cannot be changed, unless the app saves copies of them on disk and uses the embed files only as backup.

Comment: We are providing industry software for customers without no internet and the need for a offline installation, but this is not the point, since I could send the update as zip and include the frontend folder as well. It would be a preference of mine, this it would not be possible to change the frontend code after the program is compiled. At least not permanetly. Actually the python pre-process step sounds reasonable. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: if I understood your problem correctly then I think the best solution is to create an iso file that autorun your executable file

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are restricted with your C++ backend, there are multiple routes you can take to make your process scalable and dev friendly.
Here are just two options, but there can be many more that you can take!

1. Serving your HTML files separately from your C++ backend.
   For eg: Every new html file generated should automatically push the changes to the directory to a github repository, which would start a Github Action / CI / CD process to update a webpage for your HTML files hosted on [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) (or Netlify, or Github Pages even) for free.
   Now you can have this newly hosted webpage embedded as an iframe within your C++ backend and everytime there is a new HTML file generated, and subsequent deployment of the static file, you should be able to see it on your C++ hosted server as well.
2. Update your C++ code to continuously listen to any changes to a new directory and everytime you generate an HTML you should add it to that directory on the server (either by adding an endpoint that allows you as an admin to add files to the server, or by having the generation of HTML occur on the server itself). The C++ code listening for the changes to the directory should be able to help you update any new pages that might have been added or updated!
3. You can build all the html required for the user and then send that in the response of the request instead of using iframes/embedding content. You can build a new endpoint just for this purpose and generate the content at runtime.
4. ...
5. ..
6. Take whichever you are comfortable with!

Whichever way you go, know that as long as the files are hosted SOMEWHERE on the internet, you should be able to setup an iframe/redirect towards that page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Shrey for your reply, but unfortunately that is not an answer to my question.  Of course there are many ways to implement a frontend. As you can see in my question, I already host the frontend from a folder. Since the application runs on a offline computer there is no option for internet. But nevertheless, I didnt ask for solutions to host a frontend - I wanted to know if its possible to bake in frontend files into the binary.